# send signals to process using its pid

Tags: shell, signals, sh, kill, pid

Hell all,

I am trying to write a shell script to run a program and send a sequence of signal with delay between them. I wrote the following code.

```
#!/bin/sh

KNOCK="KNOCK"
export KNOCK
./knock &
knockPID=$!

kill -SIGUSR2 $knockPID
kill -SIGUSR2 $knockPID
kill -SIGUSR1 $knockPID
sleep 2s;
kill -SIGUSR1 $knockPID
kill -SIGUSR2 $knockPID
```

I keep getting the following error for each of the kill commands

```
kill: Illegal option -S
```

your help is appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? Look at the man page for `kill` for you system - many of them support different syntax. Also, what shell? `kill` is a builtin in many shells.

Comment: what about `kill --signal SIGUSR2 $knockPID`?

Comment: using --signal changed the error to Illegal option --

Comment: You should add what shell you are using because `/bin/sh` does not link to the same  shell on every system. You can run `ls -l $(which sh)` to see the link.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, named signal arguments for the `kill` command are [*"recognized in a case-independent fashion, without the SIG prefix"*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/kill.html).  So, you want:

```
kill -USR1 $knockPID
```

and so on.

Comment: This is how to do it with `dash` which is sometimes (and it's good) the shell that `/bin/sh` links to.

Answer (score 0):

```
kill -s SIGUSR2 $knockPID
```

should probably work on all modern OSes.

Comment: that didn't work, I get a different error now.  kill: invalid signal number or name: SIGUSR2

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, I fixed it by using a different shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
```